# VBA If a cell font colour = "x" then offset from the cell = "y" worksheet chang event

Tags: excel, vba

I used a similar version of the below code to time stamp every time there's change that meets certain criteria. I can't figure out why the below code isn't working.

If a cell font colour equals 14 (dark blue) then it will move 5 columns to the right and change a cell value to "ROOF".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Colour(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ptInt As Range
    Dim rangeCell As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim cCell As Integer

    Set ptInt = Intersect(Target, Range("D12:D70"))
   If Not ptInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rangeCell In ptInt
        cCell = rangeCell.Font.ColorIndex
        If cCell = 14 Then
            Set sCell = rangeCell.Offset(0, 5)

                sCell.Value = "ROOF"

            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

EDIT:

I managed to make the code do what I wanted, however, it only triggers if a cell value is changed, is it possible to make it trigger when font is changed?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rInt As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim tCell As Range

    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("G12:G116"))
   If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rInt
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex = 23 Then
            Set tCell = rCell.Offset(0, 7)
            'If IsEmpty(tCell) Then
                tCell = "ROOF"

                   'End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit2:

I changed the macro from Worksheet_Change to Worksheet_Calculate. That way it will update everytime the sheet is recalculated. Exactly what I needed. Thank you all for help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rInt As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim tCell As Range
    Set rInt = Range("G12:G116,V12:V116")
   If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rInt

        If rCell.Font.ColorIndex = 23 Then
            Set tCell = rCell.Offset(0, 7)
                tCell = "ROOF"
       ElseIf rCell.Font.ColorIndex = 14 Then
            Set tCell = rCell.Offset(0, 7)
                tCell = "ROOF2"
        Else
       Set tCell = rCell.Offset(0, 7)
        tCell = ""

            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Error message?  Unexpected behavior?  Did you check to see if your code was getting into the if block as expected?  Did you check to see what the row/column/font color properties of rangeCell are, and if they are what you expect?

Comment: Hi

To be honest I don't know how to do it. It's an event change code so it's 'live'.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't an event that will fire when just a format is changed. You have to change the value for `Worksheet_Change` to execute.

Comment: You could use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` with a small modification but it would run through and check the entire range of cells (G12:G116) each time you clicked into _any_ cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this to be done with a worksheet event, here's a possible solution using the `SelectionChange` event. Excel does not have an event that fires when just a format change occurs. This macro will check the entire range of cells (G12:G116) whenever *any* cell is clicked into.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim checkRange As Range

    Set checkRange = Range("G12:G116")
    For Each rCell In checkRange
        If rCell.Font.ColorIndex = 23 Then ' tailor this to your needs
            rCell.Offset(0, 7).value = "ROOF"
        End if
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: This macro will not run until you have clicked into another cell after changing the font color.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for you help. I changed worksheet_change to worksheet_calculate and it works exactly how I needed it to. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Colour(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ptInt As Range
    Dim rangeCell As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim cCell As Integer

    Set ptInt = Intersect(Target, Range("D12:D70"))
   If Not ptInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rangeCell In ptInt
        cCell = rangeCell.Font.Color
        If cCell = 6299648 Then
            Set sCell = rangeCell.Offset(0, 5)

                sCell.Value = "ROOF"

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem was with the line `rangeCell.Font.ColorIndex`
I replaced it with the line `rangeCell.Font.Color` and that made dark blue value 6299648.

To see different values to different colors use `MsgBox(rangeCell.Font.Color)`.

Comment: Two things wrong here. 1) `.Interior.ColorIndex` is for cell fill color. They are looking for a font color change. 2) The `Worksheet_Change` event won't fire if just the font (or fill color) is changed.

Comment: Hi
First of all thank you for your time.

Your code checks for the background colour. I need to check for font colour.

I am going to post an edit on the original post as I have managed to make the code work, however, I need it to trigger when font colour is changed.

Comment: @Porcupine911 Is there a way to trigger it if the font color changes?

Comment: @Brian You can use ```Worksheet_Change``` insted of  ```Worksheet_Colour``` and when you unselect the text it runs so it will run when you change the text font.

Comment: @amitklein It works thank you, but would it be possible to trigger it through a different macro ? I've got a macro that extracts data from my spreadsheet, I could force the 'refresh' priorit to extracting the data.

Comment: I can't find any solution to this problem, can't you call is in the second function before extracting the data?